# Add a constraint to a previous query with 3 select

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, select

I have this query:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(
    'SELECT * 
    FROM table_shots 
    WHERE idmatch in (
                        select * 
                        from (
                            SELECT mc_id 
                            FROM table_matches 
                            WHERE mc_hometeam = '. $idTeam .' 
                            OR mc_awayteam = '. $idTeam .' 
                            ORDER BY mc_date desc 
                            LIMIT '. $num .'
                            ) temp_tab
                    )'
                );
```

**Now i need to add another condition to** `table_shots` .

table_shots has also this field: `teamtype`. This field can have two values: `home_team` or `away_team`.

Now (in my perspective) what we need is to find a way to know from the third `SELECT` if the `$idTeam` was in `mc_hometeam` or `mc_awayteam` (from `table_matches`) in order to add the new condition.

The new condition will be added to the table `table_shots` (teorically) like this: `AND teamtype = home_team` (**if the `$idTeam` was in `mc_hometeam` from `table_matches`** ) or `AND teamtype = away_team` (**if the `$idTeam` was in `mc_awayteam` from `table_matches`** ).

Suggestions to do this?

This one is hard i know, surprise me ;)

Comment: I think you are talking about **conditions**, not constraints. Constraints prevent data corruption when inserting, updating, and deleting data. Conditions are useful to filter rows during a `select`.

Comment: @TheImpaler you rigth, i've fixed it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a simple join instead of multiple selects?

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ts.* 
    FROM table_shots AS ts 
    JOIN table_matches AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id
    WHERE (mc_hometeam = '. $idTeam .' AND teamtype = 'home_team') OR (mc_awayteam = '. $idTeam .' AND teamtype = 'away_team')
    ORDER BY mc_date desc 
    LIMIT '. $num);
```

Also, I would recommend using PDO and parameters, instead of concatenating the $idTeam var to the query string.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ts.* 
    FROM table_shots AS ts 
    JOIN table_matches AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id
    WHERE (mc_hometeam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'home_team') OR (mc_awayteam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'away_team')
    ORDER BY mc_date desc 
    LIMIT '. $num);
$stmt->execute([':idTeam' => $idTeam]);
```

**Edit:** You're right, the LIMIT is in the wrong place. At first glance, combining the two should work.

**Edit2:** The first query below works, but in the second, I put the min() in the wrong place. Third one had the same problem. Fixed them.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ts.* 
    FROM table_shots AS ts 
    JOIN table_matches AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id
    WHERE ((mc_hometeam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'home_team') OR (mc_awayteam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'away_team'))
    AND idmatch in (
                        select * 
                        from (
                            SELECT mc_id 
                            FROM table_matches 
                            WHERE mc_hometeam = :idTeam 
                            OR mc_awayteam = :idTeam 
                            ORDER BY mc_date desc 
                            LIMIT '. $num .'
                            ) temp_tab
                    ));
$stmt->execute([':idTeam' => $idTeam]);
```

Or this approach could work too, I'm not sure which is better.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ts.* 
    FROM table_shots AS ts 
    JOIN table_matches AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id
    WHERE ((mc_hometeam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'home_team') OR (mc_awayteam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'away_team'))
    AND mc_date >= (
                        SELECT min(mc_date)
                        FROM (
                            SELECT mc_date
                            FROM table_matches 
                            WHERE mc_hometeam = :idTeam 
                            OR mc_awayteam = :idTeam 
                            ORDER BY mc_date desc 
                            LIMIT '. $num .'
                            ) temp_tab
                    ));
$stmt->execute([':idTeam' => $idTeam]);
```

Or, of course you could get the minDate in a separate query. This is more readable I think.

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT min(mc_date)
                        FROM (
                            SELECT mc_date
                            FROM table_matches 
                            WHERE mc_hometeam = :idTeam 
                            OR mc_awayteam = :idTeam 
                            ORDER BY mc_date desc 
                            LIMIT '. $num .'
                            ) temp_tab);
$stmt->execute([':idTeam' => $idTeam]);
$result = $stmt->fetch(\PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ts.* 
    FROM table_shots AS ts 
    JOIN table_matches AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id
    WHERE ((mc_hometeam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'home_team') OR (mc_awayteam = :idTeam AND teamtype = 'away_team'))
    AND mc_date >= :minDate');

$stmt->execute([':idTeam' => $idTeam, ':minDate' => $result['minDate']]);
```

Comment: this works but the problem is that the "ORDER BY mc_date desc LIMIT '. $num" is ordering and limiting the final result and i want it only to work only on "table_matches". Example: ... AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id ORDER BY mc_date desc LIMIT '. $num .' WHERE (mc_hometeam ...  How can i do this? Its so close now...

Comment: In the end it would something like this: $stmt = $conn->prepare('SELECT ts.* 
    FROM '. $tableRef .' AS ts 
    JOIN table_matches AS tm ON ts.idmatch = tm.mc_id ORDER BY mc_date desc LIMIT '. $num.'
    WHERE (mc_hometeam = '. $idTeam .' AND teamtype = "home_team") OR (mc_awayteam = '. $idTeam .' AND teamtype = "away_team")
    ');

Comment: Edit: No, sorry I see what you mean. Let me think about it. (Maybe I'm missing something, but limiting the match ids to the first $num freshest ones, and then only selecting the shots which have those match ids is the same as what I did with the join.)

Comment: Edited the answer. I hope this is what you were looking for.

Comment: Edit: i was testing the query and there is only 1 thing that is not working: the "LIMIT" . If i put 1 or other number greater its always  showing the records for all games of the team that matches the previous conditions in the query.

Comment: example: if "$num" is equal to 2, it will return only the 2 first id's of column "mc_id" WHERE mc_hometeam = :idTeam 
                            OR mc_awayteam = :idTeam. And then with those 2 id's returned we will get the records from "table_shots" based on the conditions made earlier (these conditions are correct, i think what only needs to be fixed is the last "AND" condition) @bnorb

Comment: Edit: Okay, I see what's the problem.